# Why doesn't the set remove duplicates from the sorted list?

Tags: java, groovy

Why doesn't the set remove duplicates from the sorted list ? I have sorted the dates in ascending order which the first printed line shows but the set isn't removing the duplicates. Why is that ? 
The program prints:
[Mon Apr 20 12:27:47 CDT 2009, Mon Apr 20 12:27:47 CDT 2009, Sun Dec 20 12:27:47 CST 2009]
[Sun Dec 20 12:27:47 CST 2009, Mon Apr 20 12:27:47 CDT 2009, Mon Apr 20 12:27:47 CDT 2009]

Shouldn't creating a set remove the duplicate date from the collection ?

```
    def void testLoadDoc()
     {
     Date date1 = getCurrentDate(3,20,2009)
     Date date2 = getCurrentDate(11,20,2009)
     Date date3 = getCurrentDate(3,20,2009)


     List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
     dates.add(date2);
     dates.add(date1);
     dates.add(date3);

     Collections.sort(dates, new CurrencyDateComparator());
     Set uniqueDates = new HashSet(dates)

     println dates
     println uniqueDates

 }


 private Date getCurrentDate(int month, int day, int year)
 {

     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.set(YEAR, year);
     cal.set(MONTH, month);
     cal.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
     return cal.getTime();

 }
}

class CurrencyDateComparator implements Comparator
{
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.util.Comparator#compare(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
     */
    public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1)
    {
        Date p = (Date) arg0;
        Date q = (Date) arg1;

        if (p.before(q))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (p.after(q))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (o instanceof CurrencyDateComparator)
        {
            CurrencyDateComparator c = (CurrencyDateComparator) o;

            return this.equals(o);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why have you overridden `equals` in your `Comparator`?

Comment: You can delete the equals() method as it never returns `true` it will either return false or Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

All your dates have different millisecond values, that are not printed in your traces. Set the milliseconds to 0.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: the OP is using a HashSet. He can't ignore the milliseconds.

Comment: Good point. I skipped a step. Using TreeSet with a custom comparator and it will sort them and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

### First

`java.util.Date` carries time information with it, [you need to zero out the time information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28%29) then set what you want to be set or exclude the time portion from the comparison inside your custom `Comparator`.

## Second

Your custom `Comparator` is buggy and redundant. `java.util.Date` already implements `Comparable` so you don't need to compare dates again, just called `.compare()` on the first `Date` instance with the second one as an argument.

## Third

Also remember that `MONTHS` are ZERO based in Caledar. January == `0` not `1`.

## Fourth

Never rely on the default `toString()` on `java.util.Date`, always use a `SimpleDateFormatter` instance that displays the entire time stamp down to the milliseconds including a `TimeZone` ( `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` ), preferably ISO-8601 and `UTC` TimeZone for deterministic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Calendar.getInstance()` it returns "now" to millisecond precision.  Changing the Y-M-D fields does not clear any of that out, so your two dates are likely off by a millisecond or twenty, which is not included in the default `toString()` implementation that you're seeing output from.

If you want to set a calendar to a specific time, it is simplest to `clear()` it first before starting to set fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Calendar.getInstance()`, you get a `Calendar` initialized with the current time.  This includes hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.  Call [`clearTime()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Calendar.html#clearTime%28%29) on it to zero them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this collection instead

```
Set<Date> dates = new TreeSet<Date>(CurrencyDateComparator.INSTANCE);
dates.add(date2);
dates.add(date1);
dates.add(date3);

enum CurrencyDateComparator implements Comparator<Date> {
    INSTANCE;

    static final long MILLI_PER_DAY = 86400000L;
    public int compare(Date d1, Date d2) {
        // older versions of Java can use Double.compare()
        return Long.compare(d1.getTime() / MILLIS_PER_DAY, d2.getTime() / MILLIS_PER_DAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't make two dates equal if they're on the same day, even in the UTC timezone. Some days have more than 24 hours. Some have less.

Comment: I am pretty sure that without daylight savings, every day has the same length in Java.  He could see issues with daylight savings but he would have to be very unlucky. Technically Java only supports GMT not leap seconds in UTC.

Comment: DST is only part of the problem. If the time zone is not UTC, that won't work.

Comment: Really he should be using LocalDate from Joda Time.